# Laravel Websockets Error in connection Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-websockets

Im trying to set up laravel websockets on localhost using [this library](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets)

And I am getting this error
[image]

I have installed the package and started the service on my localhost running `php artisan websockets:serve`

my Bootstrap.js is:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
});
window.Echo.channel('DemoChannel').listen('WebsocketDemoEvent',(e) => function() {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

create a new middleware:  app/Http/Middleware/cors.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

add the cors middleware to app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //default laravel middleware
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

add the new cors middleware to your route

```
Route::get('/broadcast', function () {
    broadcast(new hello());
});
})-> middleware('cors');
```

---caution---
this will now accept requests from ANYWHERE.

this is fine on localhost but when you move to a live server you need to change:

```
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
```

to

```
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://www.yourdomain.com')
```

or you need to create an api key to pass along with each request so you can have the public api (not reccomended but is a viable workaround)

Comment: No it is not working.Still it is showing the same error

Comment: can you share your code with those additions? so i can see what's going on

Comment: Do you want to see the events?

Comment: looking at the error again, i see it's trying to communicate with pusher, if you are hosing your own ws server with ws:serve, what are you sending to pusher?

Comment: @aidanbyrne if you look closer it is a fallback,
it tries the its own WShost first that fails then it fallsback on the pusher main site. So they quetion is more why does the first request fail.